# How to install pandas for python 2 and not on my default python 3.6?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to install pandas for python2 on my ubuntu 18.04.

When I try to install pandas using

```
pip install pandas
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /home/apoorv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.5.0 in /home/apoorv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.0 in /home/apoorv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /home/apoorv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas) (2018.5)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /home/apoorv/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas) (1.12.0)
```

The error I'm getting:

```
apoorv@apoorv:~/Desktop$ python2
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pandas
>>>
```

How to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python 2 package containing the pandas library is called `python-pandas`:

```
sudo apt install python-pandas
```